# Displaying message using textEdit function in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, qt-designer, settext, qtextedit

I've created a GUI using QT Designer and a python program that gives functionality to the buttons in the GUI. I have two buttons: Calibrate and Measure. After each button is clicked, there is some data analysis and eventually some value is displayed using the textEdit function. The value is displayed through the use of this function:

```
self.textEdit.clear()
self.textEdit.setText('Absorbance: {0}'.format(absorbance))
```

This value is only displayed after all the analysis is complete, but this takes maybe 15 seconds. During the 15 second waiting time I would like to show a message that says something like "Measuring... Please Wait". However, I've tried to add another textEdit line of code but it just ignores it and continues to only display the very last textEdit function after the button is clicked and the analysis is complete.

I'm not entirely sure how else to go about displaying an intermediary message, but if any one has suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try putting `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` after setting the message.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much.